# Is there any pattern for executing all the registered implementations of an interface?

Tags: asp.net-core, design-patterns, .net-core

I have a Exception handling middleware in asp.net core app, which uses the below IExceptionHandler to handle exceptions

```
public interface IExceptionHandler<T> where T:Exception
{
    ProblemDetails HandleException(T exception);
}
```

I want to register different kinds of exception handlers such as

```
// Handles Sql based exceptions
public class SqlExceptionHandler: IExceptionHandler<SqlException>
{
    public ProblemDetails Handle(SqlException exception);
}

// Handles File based exceptions 
public class IOExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler<IOException>
{
    public ProblemDetails Handle(IOException exception);
}

// Handles all the exceptions that are not handled by any handlers
public class ExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler<Exception>
{
    public ProblemDetails Handle(Exception exception)
}
```

when the exception middleware gets triggered, i want the exception handler to be triggered automatically based on the type, if the exception is unhandled by any of these then want to have ExceptionHandler handle the exception.

Is it possible to trigger the exception handler instance automatically based on type?
Also, I want this IExceptionHandler to be extensible such that in future if i want to handle any other type of Exception, I just register the implementation

Comment: Just interesting, could you please share what is structure of `ProblemDetails`? By the way, for making it to work you have add order mechanism somehow. I mean, let's say some `SqlException` is thrown, how you will now that whether you have to execute `SqlExceptionHandler`, but not `ExceptionHandler`?

Comment: The ProblemDetails is from Microsoft mvc, 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails?view=aspnetcore-3.0', and with some property 'IsExceptionHandled' maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one took me a while to figure out, but was fun and challenging, and finally have a working solution.

**Also, I do understand this is probably not what you were looking for.** It would be nice if ASP provided something out of the box that you could register in the Startup class, which I assume is what you **were** looking for.

If anyone out there knows of such a feature I would love a better solution!!

Here is the `[TestMethod]` I used that can be placed in a MSTest `[TestClass]`

```
[TestMethod]
public void _58790281()
{
    try
    {
        throw new IOException("Text IO Exception");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        PassExceptionToHandler(e);
    }
}

private void PassExceptionToHandler(Exception ex)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IExceptionHandler<>));
    List<Type> concreteTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(a => !a.IsInterface).ToList();
    Type currentExceptionHandlerType = concreteTypes
        .FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetInterfaces().Any(i =>
            i.IsGenericType
            && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IExceptionHandler<>)
            && i.GenericTypeArguments.Any(ii => ii == ex.GetType())));

    MethodInfo exceptionHandlerMethod = currentExceptionHandlerType.GetMethod("HandleException");

    var exceptionHanderInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(currentExceptionHandlerType);
    exceptionHandlerMethod.Invoke(exceptionHanderInstance, new object[] { ex });
}
```

EDIT: Of course you will want to isolate your handlers so that the reflection cost is less, maybe place them in their own assembly or modify this to get types from a namespace or something so it's not looking at all the types in your main assembly.

EDIT_01: ASP.Net Core does actually provide some configuration for global exception handling, just came across this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: Thanks, this will probably lead to what i want, so tweaking your solution, instead of scanning the assembly, i am trying to add a property to hold all the registered handler instances of signature 'public IEnumerable<IExceptionHandler<Exception>> Handlers' {get;set;}', but the thing is i can add Handler of type 'IExceptionHandler<Exception>' obviously but not of type ''IExceptionHandler<SqlExceptionHandler>' which is derived from 'IExceptionHandler<SqlException>', may be some 'Covariance/Conravariance' issue. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: @kartikrajan If you want to keep a list of 'registered' handlers instead of scanning the assembly, you could just have a List<Type> with all of the handlers you want to pick from based on the exception type.

So you'd replace the current `concreteTypes` list variable with this deceleration instead. (Sorry there's no multiline code formatting here)


`List<Type> concreteTypes = new List<Type>
{
 typeof(SqlExceptionHandler),
 typeof(IOExceptionHandler),
 typeof(ExceptionHandler)
};`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) library for scanning assembly for all implementations of any interface and automatically register them with the help of that library.
For example:

```
services.Scan(scan => scan
  .FromCallingAssembly()
    .AddClasses(x=> x.AssignableTo(typeof(IOpenGeneric<>))) // Can close generic types
      .AsImplementedInterfaces()
      .WithScopedLifetime()
);
```

And then you can make a call to `IServiceProvider` inside middleware to get all registered implementations and then you need a bit of reflection or dynamic dispatching to execute `Handle` method of the required exception handler.
Also, you have to somehow preserve orders of that exception handlers. Let me explain what I mean. For example, in case of `SqlException` you have to execute `SqlExceptionHandler` (more specific) rather than `ExceptionHandler`. How are you going to find out which handler is more specific one?

Of course all of this can be done. But, I think it will ***introduce needless complexity*** to the your code-base.

I think it will be better to create one base exception [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.0).
And then multiple derived middlewares. And the good thing is that, as noted in [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#order):

> The order that middleware components are added in the
>   Startup.Configure method defines the order in which the middleware
>   components are invoked on requests.

As you see, with that approach order problem will be solved automatically.

Here is some sample code:

```
 public abstract class BaseExceptionHandlingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _nextMiddlewareRequestDelegate;

        public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate nextMiddlewareRequestDelegate)
        {
            _nextMiddlewareRequestDelegate = nextMiddlewareRequestDelegate;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _nextMiddlewareRequestDelegate(context);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                await HandleExceptionAsync(context, exception);
            }
        }

        private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
        {
            var errorDescription = exception.Message;
            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error = errorDescription });

            context.Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Json;
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)DetermineStatusCode(exception);
            return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
        }

        protected virtual HttpStatusCode DetermineStatusCode(Exception exception);
    }
```

And create let's say `SqlExceptionHandlinMiddleware`, `IOExceptionHandlinMiddleware`, `GeneralExceptionHandlinMiddleware`  and then just override `DetermineStatusCode`.

And then register them so:

```
builder.UseMiddleware<SqlExceptionHandlinMiddleware>();
builder.UseMiddleware<IOExceptionHandlinMiddleware>();
builder.UseMiddleware<GeneralExceptionHandlinMiddleware>();
```